# Does `yield return false;` have special meaning in Unity3d C# scripts?

Tags: c#, unity

In Unity, we have some special things for coroutines that are additional to normal C#.

for example, we can use

`yield return WaitForSeconds(5.f);`

to have a coroutine wait 5 seconds before continuing.

What do `yield return false;` and `yield return true;` do?

Comment: hm I'm not sure if `yield return true` does something special. But `yield return null` simply pauses for a frame, so I suspect that `yield return false` has the exact same effect (also `yield return 0` since 0 false null are all the same under the hood)

Comment: @jhocking “since 0 false null are all the same under the hood” Why does that matter? C# is very much a strongly-typed language, so most of the time, how something looks “under the hood” doesn't matter. For example, you can't just do `if (0)` or `if (null)`, unlike in C and C++.

Comment: *shrug* then it doesn't matter. all I know is that `yield return 0` works; apparently because of the reason MLM explained

Comment: This is *not* additional to normal C#. The [`yield` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) has been around since at least C# 2.0. All Unity does is call it *coroutine* and handles the generated iterator and the values returned from it in a way that you can cause non-blocking delays in the execution of your code.

Comment: If I were in a .NET C# project made with Visual Studio without Unity and I did `yield return WaitForSeconds(5.f);` it would not compile. I am aware that `yield` is not new. But you can do different things with it in Unity, and they are not clear at all in their documentation about what is special to Unity and what is not.

Comment: @Almo: That is simply because `WaitForSeconds` is not declared. As soon as you declare a method called `WaitForSeconds` that takes a float argument and that returns the element type of the enumeration you are implementing, it would compile again. Hence, `yield` is not special to Unity. If anything, the `WaitForSeconds` method is special to Unity, but even then, it does not extend the *language* C#, but is simply an extra method that was written using standard C#.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I know it does not extend C#. I never said it did. I said you can do different things with `yield` related to coroutines in Unity, and their documentation isn't clear about what's available. I know that `WaitForSeconds` has to be declared. The problem is that Unity doesn't tell you in an obvious place *what* is declared that can be used in this instance. I was never under the impression that this was an "extension to the language".

Comment: @Almo: Ok; I just thought the statement "that are additional to normal C#" could be understood as though there were some additions to the normal C# language.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Right. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The only possible yield values the scheduler understands are:
>
> - Classes derived from `YieldInstruction` (`WaitForSeconds`, `WaitForEndOfFrame`, `WaitForFixedUpdate`, `AssetBundleCreateRequest`, `AssetBundleRequest` and Coroutine
> - a `WWW` object
> - **"any other value"** which isn't one of the above.
>
> If **"any other value"** is yielded (which includes "null" a string value any other basic type such as int, **bool**, ... or a reference to an arbitrary object which isn't one of the above mentioned) the scheduler will **"schedule" the coroutine for the next frame**.
>
> *- [Bunny83 answer: Prominent member on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/636109/yieldinstructions-from-unmanaged-land-eg-waitforse.html#answer-container-636147)*

The `WaitForEndOfFrame` and others of the like, are just blank functions that tag the [`YieldInstruction`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) in order to decide what to do in the engine.

The default case seems to be [`WaitForEndOfFrame`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html). So if you `yield return` something that doesn't have a special meaning, such as a bool, it is the same as [`WaitForEndOfFrame`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html).

There doesn't seem to be any official documentation on this behavior.

---

### Update

**[rutter](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/33377/rutter)** commented about another special case: `yield return null`

All of the Unity Coroutines including `yield return null`, run before the frame renders except for `WaitForEndOfFrame`. You can find **[rutter](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/33377/rutter)**'s [awesome answer over at Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/755196/yield-return-null-vs-yield-return-waitforendoffram.html#answer-container-755208) explaining this further (nice diagrams included).

Comment: It's common to assume that yielding `null` and `WaitForEndOfFrame` are the same, but [they are actually slightly different](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/755196/yield-return-null-vs-yield-return-waitforendoffram.html?sort=oldest), as detailed at the [execution order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) manual page.