# Overriding CoRoutine doesn't execute base code

Tags: unity, coroutines

I want to have a `CoRoutine` declared as `virtual` in parent class and then overridden in child classes.

```
protected override IEnumerator f(Vector3 to)
{
...
    yield return base.f(to);
...
}
```

What happens (or doesn't happen) is that the base code doesn't get executed. Debuggin it I step into the `base.f(to)` and the cursor just stand on function name. If I press step next control returns to the child.

I really have no clue how to handle this situation. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerators (more specifically, yield return) are special and magic pieces of syntax sugar.

What is happening is that the compiler creates (at compile time) a class that packages all the state of the function you wrote. And then substitutes the function with a stub that creates an instance of the class and returns it.

So you're not running your code in `yield return base.f(to)`, you're just creating an object and returning it.

CoRoutines are also special and magic pieces of Unity, they iterate over what is returned and if given some special type of value it does something else special.

These things include:

- Scheduling the CoRoutine to be continued at some later point in time
- I have no idea I don't use that much Unity to be honest :)

So what you're returning from your CoRoutine (the override) is an IEnumerator, Unity doesn't know what to do with the coroutine so it doesn't do anything special and asks for the next value. Which runs the bit after your `yield return` and... stops, because there's nothing more to be done.

What you should do is this:

```
protected override IEnumerator f(Vector3 to)
{
...
    var baseVal = base.f(to);
    while ( true ) {
       yield return baseVal.Current;
       if ( baseVal.MoveNext() == False ) break;
    }
...
}
```

I don't have access to an Unity setup at this time so this is untested, I also don't know what happens with an IEnumerator that never returns a single value (or if that is even legal).

Comment: Here's a question about what values you can (usefully) return from coroutines, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81377/does-yield-return-false-have-special-meaning-in-unity3d-c-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
  protected override IEnumerator f(Vector3 to)
  {
  ...
      yield return StartCoroutine(base.f(to));
  ...
  }
```

Coroutine inherits from YieldInstruction, and yielding on one will cause your coroutine to pause until the other coroutine completes.

Comment: Does this actually work? From what I've read the [only return values understood to do anything but delay a frame](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81377/does-yield-return-false-have-special-meaning-in-unity3d-c-scripts) are YieldInstructions, I would think a coroutine wouldn't fit.